# How to move files to ExternalStorage after APK installation?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm developing an application about a local guide, this app has audios/videos.

After the installation i want to move these media resources to the external storage. How can i do that?

I want to avoid the "Android Move To SD Card Feature" if its possible.

If I use the `/resource/` folder (with `/res/raw/` I think it's impossible) **can I move the files to SD Card and after delete them from the internal memory? How?**

Other way?

Thanks.

I see a similar question in stackoverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-to)) but it's not exactly the same, and the there's no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a comment in the answer to the question you linked says, you can't delete files from the apk, no matter where you put them (btw, what's `/resource/` dir??). This way, it would only make sense if you're copying some "default" file that will be modified during app's life.

The only way, if you don't want / can't use App2SD, is downloading the files to sd.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I suppose the best option is import the data from internet or SD card.

Comment: as you say, there is no option. Now I need to convert the files or make an installer to download the content to the Sd Card.