# How do you make an apk create a file on the sdcard when the apk is installed?

Tags: android, installation, apk, sd-card, createfile

I am very new to android development and am looking for a way to modify existing source-code in eclipse so that when the apk is installed, an xml file is copied from inside the apk to a specific folder on the external storage.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: to add a little detail as to what I am trying to do, I have code for an app that downloads files from a webserver and then does stuff with them. This process of getting the files is currently handled in a gui in the app. Once the file is downloaded to the sd card, the program then does stuff with it. What I want to do is to have the app start off with the correct file and never expose the user to the selection/download part of the GUI. I'm looking for the simplest way to do this as I am not really a coder.

Answer (score 4):

See the question and answer here...[Android: How to create a directory on the SD Card and copy files from /res/raw to it??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-to)

**EDIT**: Thinking about it, I use the /assets folder and not /res/raw. This is roughly what I do...

First get a valid folder on your external storage (normally SD card)...

```
File myFilesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.mycompany.myApp/files");
```

Replace `com.mycompany.myApp` in the path above with your app's package name.

Then the following will copy all files from the assets folder with filenames beginning with "xyz", e.g., xyz123.txt, xyz456.xml etc.

```
try {
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    String[] list = am.list("");
    for (String s:list) {
        if (s.startsWith("xyz")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Copying asset file " + s);
            InputStream inStream = am.open(s);
            int size = inStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inStream.read(buffer);
            inStream.close();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFilesDir + "/" + s);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Better to handle specific exceptions such as IOException etc
    // as this is just a catch-all
}
```

Note you'll need the following permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like what I'm looking for, but I'm too inept to implement it based on that answer. I'm not really a coder and I'm working on a bit of a kludge here. Is there any way you could show me a code snippet of what this would actually look like when correctly implemented?

Comment: @m13124: See from EDIT in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks MisterSquonk! I will give this a try :)

Comment: And is there a way to do it during APK installation?

Comment: @FlashThunder : No. Unlike something like a Windows app installation, there is no way to customize the Android app procedure. The closest you can get is to do the copying the first time the app is run.