# How to copy a xml file from res/raw folder to sd card of android?

Tags: android

I want to copy a xml file from res/raw folder to the sd card. This question is actually specific to the ODK Collect. But any help would be appreciated. I have looked at [Android: How to create a directory on the SD Card and copy files from /res/raw to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-to) and other similar posts on the web but I was still unable to copy. Maybe, its because I am working on ODK Collect. 
This is my code for copying the file:

```
       try {
         InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.problem2);
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Collect.FORMS_PATH+"/problem2");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();

        }           
     catch(IOException e) { }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, its a software for xforms, etc...

Comment: What is the value of Collect.FORMS_PATH ?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/odk/forms"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void copyFiles() throws IOException{

        InputStream myInput = m_Context.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME_KEPT_IN_ASSET_FOLDER);
        String outFileName = "/data/data/your.package.name/folder/";
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```