# Copying raw file into SDCard?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, file-copying

I've some audio files in my `res/raw` folder. For some reasons, i want to copy this files to my SDCard When, my application starts.

How can i done this? Anyone guide me?

Comment: why you want to copy if its already in SDCard?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to delete that words. Check my edited question now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to create a directory on the SD Card and copy files from /res/raw to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-t)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Read from the resource, write to a file on the SD card:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myresource);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(somePathOnSdCard);
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

try {
   while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
      out.write(buff, 0, read);
   }
} finally {
     in.close();
     out.close();
}
```

Comment: How do i get the number of bytes copied just as we can publish progress while downloading file from internet.

Comment: @newBie Each time through the while loop it's copying 1024 bytes

Comment: Thanks for the solution!
How do you decide the size of the buffer to be 1024?

Comment: It's a common idiom in Java, and 1024 is a nice round number :). Could be adjusted depending on your resources, but probably the OS is already smart enough to cache the file once you hit it, so probably no measurable difference unless are a really huge resource, maybe.

Answer (score 7):

### Copy file from raw to External Storage:

This is a method that i use to do this job, this method receive the resource id, and the name desired for storage, for example:

```
copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.mysound, "jorgesys_sound.mp3");
```

method:

```
private void copyFiletoExternalStorage(int resourceId, String resourceName){
    String pathSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + resourceName;
    try{
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        out = new FileOutputStream(pathSDCard);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Environment.**getExternalStorageDirectory()** this method is
> deprecated in API level 29 and it will not allow to create a
> directory/file on given path.

Below code is working for creating directory and downloading file from /res/raw directory.

> If your device have **Android 10 (API Level 29) or greater** it will
> download your file on below location
>
> File manager--> Storage -->
> Android --> data --> com.yourapp.packagename --> files --> FOLDER_NAME
> --> file_name.png

```
private void downloadFileFromRawFolder(){
try {
                InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(
                        getResources().getIdentifier("file_name",
                                "raw", getPackageName())); // use only file name here, don't use extension
                File fileWithinMyDir = new File(checkFolder(), "file_name.png"); //Getting a file within the dir.
                Log.e("FILEPATH ", "fileWithinMyDir " + fileWithinMyDir);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2]; //2MB file
                int read = 0;

                try {
                    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buff, 0, read);
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Download Done ");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

---

/* Create directory */

```
    private File checkFolder() {
        String path;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "FOLDER_NAME";
        } else {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FOLDER_NAME";
        }
        File dir = new File(path);
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = dir.exists();
        if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
            isDirectoryCreated = dir.mkdir();
            Log.d("Folder", "Created = " + isDirectoryCreated);
        }

        Log.d("Folder", "Created ? " + isDirectoryCreated);
        return dir;
    }
}
```