# How can I append to my text in raw file?

Tags: java, android, android-file

I mean I want to append my txt in raw file.

I use this but it cant.

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(R.raw.a, MODE_WORLD_APPEND);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
```

Comment: I don't know much about Android programming, but don't you need to change the "MODE_WORLD_READABLE"
to 
"MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE"?

Comment: @Janman yes it s true but the problem is it is not allow R.raw.a , it  is wait for string of path. But what is path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in raw are packaged with ap. So these are read only files. You cannot modify these files. You need to copy this onto filesystem and then change it.

**Edit**: Check this post [Copying raw file into SDCard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664468/copying-raw-file-into-sdcard) . Add permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if you are writing to sdcard

Comment: how I can copy this to phone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to android programming, but what I think the problem is that you can't change the R.raw files.
However, you should be able to write to an file on the device directly like this:

```
FileWriter f0 = new FileWriter("file1.txt"); 
f1.write("Hello Ersin!"); 
f1.close();
```

It should also be a lot easier to access and modify files made on the device instead of some created inside the project.