# Share sounds of app (from raw folder)

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that has some sounds, stored into raw folder of my project. For now it's only possible to reproduce it inside my app (by use MediaPlayer object).
Now i would know if is possible to take this files, and share it via intent (for example by using whatsapp intent)

Comment: check this to write a raw file to other directories. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8664527/603744

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the file to internal storage and [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to publish a `Uri` to the file that you can use with the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

Or, you can try [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to skip the copy-the-file part and publish a `Uri` straight from the raw resource.

Or, you can try using an `android.resource` `Uri`, but few apps support it for things like `ACTION_SEND`. Using either of the previous two approaches will give you better compatibility.