# Place folder inside apk and install in the sd card of the installed mobile- android

Tags: android, directory, android-sdcard

I am working on an app where i need embed the folders inside the apk, and upon installation on the client mobile, have to place that dependency folder inside the SD card. Firstly, i wanted to know if this is possible, if possible, kindly provide pointers to proceed with this.

Comment: What do you want to place in that folder?

Comment: Hope this will help you [copy res folder file into sdcard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-t

Comment: @Tarun, I need to place some pdf's, images,video and then port it along with the apk, so that once the user downloads, they can have the folder saved in the SD cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to place video audio and images in folder along with apk. 
Then first you need to know that `Google Play does not allow us to uplaod apk more than 50MB`
However you can create APK expansion files and place your all media there. That APK expansion file will automatically install in sdcard. This is the best solution google play has provided. You can try with this-

see this link - [APK Expansion](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

**Edited:-** 
 If you are not publishing your app in google play, and size does not matter then you can simply place your all media in to asset folder, and pragmatically create a folder in sdcard copy all file in that folder.

Note that - `You can not modify assets/ folder is not at runtime,` You can not delete or edit those file in asset because `APK is signed and cannot be modified at runtime.`

Comment: Hi Tarun, thanks for the update, but this is a customized app not for play store but for intended client, so 50 MB limit wont be a prob. We are deploying the app on their server