# Rename and change folder location of android resource files at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, android-resources

Is it possible to rename or change folder location (similar to cut and paste) of android resource files like .png or .xml (in drawable folder) at runtime by program. Also can I rename or create new folder like drawable at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to rename or change folder location (similar to cut and paste) of android resource files like .png or .xml (in drawable folder) at runtime by program.

No.

> Also can I rename or create new folder like drawable at runtime.

No. Resources are read-only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible to change anything in the res folder, it is read only. But you can copy / paste somewhere else and then do the editing.
If you would like to know how to copy something from the res folder, it's a good tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-t).

Comment: Not sure whether I should ask this question in another thread. So if I can't do it in runtime is it possible to do that by another app? I mean can I create one app to change resources of other app of mine?

Comment: @TapasMukherjee No, that is not possible. The resources are stored inside the APK file that is stored privately inside the system. To edit this you would need to extract the apk, unzip it, extract the resources, do your editing on them, re-compile the resources, and finally build the APK and re-install the new app. Sooo... better make some files on the SD card :)